# Elixir discover existing atoms

Tags: elixir

First, the real problem:  I've noticed a common source of run-time errors for my codebase occurring due to misspelled or re-named atoms, e.g.:

```
defmodule SomeGenServer do
  def delayed_action do
    Process.send_after(self, :delayed_action, 5_000)
  end

  #...snip...
  def handle_info(:delayed_acton, state), do: handle_delayed_action()    
end
```

This bug (`:delayed_acton` vs. `:delayed_action`) is only discovered at runtime, when `delayed_action/0` is invoked and the unexpected message crashes the GenServer 5 seconds later.  I feel like this is a problem the compiler should be able to help me find at compile time, and so I'm searching for the tools to create such a fix.

Now, on to the question:  How can I determine the atoms used within a module?  I've looked at `__ENV__`, and the functions in the `Module` and `Code` modules, and I can't find what I'm looking for, unless theres a predictable way to parse the bytecode in an `__after_compile__/2` callback?

This is a notional syntax example of what I'd eventually like to create, but I can't without being able to identify the atoms in use within `SomeGenServer`

```
defmodule SomeGenServer do
  use AtomEnforcer, atoms: [:delayed_action] 
  # This line would cause a compilation error:
  def handle_info(:delayed_acton, state), do: handle_delayed_action()    
end
```

Finally, I'm open to answers on how other people have worked this problem, whether it's via linters, module attributes, or some other cleverness.

Answer (score 3):

You can also define your atom as a module attribute, and use the module attribute everywhere.

I know this won't prevent compilation, but at least you get a nice warning.

Also, when you need to access this atom from outside module, use a function like:

```
@delayed_action :delayed_action
def delayed_action_name, do: @delayed_action
```

If you use this a lot, it might be better to write a macro that defines attribute and function for you from a list, like:

```
use AtomDefiner, atoms: [:delayed_action, :another_action]
```

and use `@delayed_action` whenever you need the atom.

Comment: I've used this approach in a few modules, though I'm a bit hung up on the lack of explicitness - @delayed_action could be anything, not necessarily an atom, and so when reading old code, it's an mild bit of indirection. As far as I can tell, it's the best existing solution.

Answer (score 2):

After a bit of searching and R&D, I found that `:beam_lib.chunks/2` in the Erlang standard library is able to parse the bytecode and extract a set of atoms from the compiled .beam:

```
iex> defmodule Test do
...>   @after_compile __MODULE__
...>   def __after_compile__(_env, bytecode) do
...>     IO.inspect(:beam_lib.chunks(bytecode, [:atoms]))
...>   end
...>
...>   def test_method do
...>     :return_value
...>   end
...> end

{:ok,
 {Test,
  [
    atoms: [
      {1, Test},
      {2, :__info__},
      {3, :functions},
      {4, :md5},
      {5, :compile},
      {6, :attributes},
      {7, :module},
      {8, :macros},
      {9, :deprecated},
      {10, :erlang},
      {11, :get_module_info},
      {12, :__after_compile__},
      {13, :beam_lib},
      {14, :chunks},
      {15, IO},
      {16, :inspect},
      {17, :test_method},
      {18, :return_value},
      {19, :module_info}
    ]
  ]}}
```

With this, I was able to cobble together a macro with the functionality I want.  Those interested can find it [here](https://github.com/meyercm/elixir_atom_enforcer), though I'm not convinced yet that it is a better solution than that offered by @vfsoraki.